# Laravel paginate(10) not working for second page

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying Laravel's **paginate** function but the URL below returns the same records every time. This means that it's showing only the first 10 records no matter which page we're on. I don't know why.

URL - https://example.com/api/getWebGalleryImages?page=3

**My Controller function**

```
public function getWebGalleryImages() {
      $galleryFIle = WebGallery::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
      return response()->json($galleryFIle, 200);
    }
```

**My route**

```
Route::get('getWebGalleryImages', 'FrontController@getWebGalleryImages');
```

**Every time same response**

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "file_name": "1627985668_download(2).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "file_name": "1627985646_istockphoto-1093301674-612x612.jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "file_name": "1627985646_images(4).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "file_name": "1627985646_images(3).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "file_name": "1627985645_images(2).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "file_name": "1627985645_images(1).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "file_name": "1627985645_download(2).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "file_name": "1627985645_download(1).jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "file_name": "1627985644_Diamond.jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "file_name": "1627985644_depositphotos_3929711-stock-photo-diamond-on-black-background.jpg",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "https://example.com/api/getWebGalleryImages?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    "last_page_url": "https://example.com/api/getWebGalleryImages?page=2",
    "next_page_url": "https://example.com/api/getWebGalleryImages?page=2",
    "path": "https://example.com/api/getWebGalleryImages",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 11
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged wordpress & codeignitor ?

Comment: sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the Response in your Question, your query seems to have **11** matched records and the your **Result Per Page** is set to **10** meaning you only have *2* pages of records. so calling `page=3` in your query is not going to get you a new record as that page is unavailable.

If you need the pagination to work set your **Result Per Page** to a lower value, let say **3** or add more data to the records.

Comment: i have many record available in database. so page=anynumber.

Comment: @roy your pages available is = `total number of query record available / result per page` in your case `11/10` = **2** as any fraction is equal to one page.
Check the `total` and `per_page` attribute in your response and do the math.

Comment: but in laravel **paginate** function manage all type logic her self. so why we apply any custom logic.

Comment: yes...it does. Was the URL in the question generated by laravel?

Comment: Yes when we call API first time using paginate function.  laravel also manage first_page_url, last_page, last_page_url, next_page_url. you can see my question in **Every time same response** part.